# Spark Streaming in Standalone cluster: how to supervise drivers in not cluster mode

Tags: spark-streaming

"supervise" is an option when submitting drivers (spark-submit) in cluster mode, unfortunately, you can not use cluster mode with Python drivers so we use client mode, does anyone know how to supervise the drivers in that mode?
It seems we will have to use an external supervisor instead, we are trying with systemd but it not start the driver at all, it seems spark-submit detached the process from the systemd ... does anyone have the same problem?
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried Yarn?

Comment: Yes we tried but a Yarn cluster consumes a lot of memory and we don't need anything from yarn (perphaps the supervisor feature).

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know alternatives (except for ... yarn or mesos ...)